# Odoo change workflow state from "more" button

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I'd like to change the state of some invoices from the 'more'-button. So when I select some invoices from the treeview and select a button 'cancel all' from under the 'more'-button.

Any help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a server action to do that. Add the next code to a XML file in your customized module:

```
<record id="change_state_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Change invoice state</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_invoice"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
action = self.your_method_to_change_state(cr, user.id, context.get('active_ids', []), context=context)
    </field>
</record>

<record id="change_state_option" model="ir.values">
    <field name="name">Change invoice state</field>
    <field name="key2" eval="'client_action_multi'"/>
    <field name="model" eval="'account.invoice'"/>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%change_state_action"/>
</record>
```

In `code` field, you must write `action = whatever python code you want`. You have to take in to account that Python code must behave as if you were working in `account.invoice` model.

So you have to put this code in a Python file in your module:

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    @api.multi
    def your_method_to_change_state(self):
        self.write({'state': 'XXXXX'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed! Do you know how to loop through all the checked records in the tree view? So I can write something like

for i in "all selected records":
        i.write({'state': 'draft'})

Comment: You are going to receive all the selected records in the variable `self` in the Python method. You can apply write to all the records at the same time as I wrote you (this is if you want to modify every record in the same way). But if not, you will be able to do: `for selected_record in self: selected_record.do_whatever_you_want`